# Дополнить число нулями слева

Tags: sql

Как можно дополнить число нулями слева, так чтобы получилась строка длины `n`?

Например, для числа 123 и `n` равного 7 должно получиться `0000123`

В идеале хотелось бы получить субд-независимое решение

Comment: СУБД какая у вас?

Comment: @Mike Ну вы в комментах уже полноценный ответ написали, оформите как полагается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полная совместимость любого произвольного запроса с произвольной СУБД невозможна. Во первых стандарты SQL описывают очень мало функций для работы со строками. Во вторых СУБД зачастую не следуют стандартам. Вот вы наверняка привыкли таблицы объединять с помощью JOIN, но в Oracle до 9й версии такой базовой вещи, как JOIN не было, была только запятая и проприетарный синтаксис для выполнения LEFT.

Что касается дополнения нулями слева, я вижу два пути:

- Использование функции `LPAD(123,7,'0')` (поддерживается MySQL, Postgresql, Oracle)
- При ее отсутствии ее замена. Вариантов довольно много, для чисел можно использовать например `substring(cast(10000000+123 as varchar),2,7)` (MS SQL, В SQLite substr).

Обратите внимание, второй вариант так же завист от СУБД. В стандарте SQL 92 оговорено, что в СУБД должна быть функция с именем substring(), однако в SQLite и Oracle такая функция существует только под именем substr().

Answer (score 1):

в MS SQL еще можно использовать format(123 ,'d4')
на выходе имеем '0123'